# Which gem is used to generate the pdf file in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation

I want to generate the pdf file in rails 3.0.0.please tell me which gem is used to generate the pdf file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use prawn: http://rubygems.org/gems/prawn

You can see how its done [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn).

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could try to use [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/), not for free of course, but they are cool.

Comment: From what I can tell PDFKit does the same thing, but it's free.

Comment: If so... Then it is better solution then mine.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit